# AJAX OPEN in FirefoxDeveloperEdition fails to work like firefox or chrome

Tags: ajax, firefox-developer-edition

Please tell how the APP ID is involved and how it can be changed.

I have been working on Ajax. The application, all in javascript at the client, works great on firefox, safari, and chrome, but not on FirefoxDeveloperEdition.

The issue is at exactly the request.open statement. It does not work on FirefoxDeveloperEdition. In the console I get the error ":" --- that is all, just the colon. As I said, that statement works perfectly on Firefox. I have the most recent version of all apps.

The selection of XMLHttpRequest is working the same in both Firefox and FirefoxDeveloperEdition. Either FirefoxDeveloperEdition is not backward compatible or not meant to be, and I cannot tell which.

Help desired.

D

Comment: See also 17047843 / ajax-open-not-working-as-expected

Comment: See also 12764934 /  ajax-open-returns-empty-error

Comment: See also 17047843 / ajax-open-not-working-as-expected ------- this is very close, and may be related.  There is a comment  which references APP ID as maybe a correction of the failure. To see the comment, look at additional comments because it is not at the top,  The comment says: 
 
awesome it works now, I have changed the app id thank you guys –  Alex Jun 11 '13 at 15:35